# A sum-product phenomenon on reciprocals

Tags: co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

Let $A \subset \mathbb F_p \setminus \{0\} $ and let $A+1/A = \{x+1/y:x,y \in A\}$.

**Question:** For fixed $c>0$, if $|A| \geq cp$, is $|A+1/A|$ at least $(1-o(1))p$ when $p \rightarrow \infty$?

**Known:**
This is false for $c<1/4$ according to Seva's comments.

Take $A$ to be $I \cap I^{-1}$ where $I=[1,m]$ and $m=(1/2-\epsilon)p$. It's sure that $A+1/A=A+A$ is not the whole $\mathbb F_p$. The hard part is that $A$ contains $(m/p)^2p(1-o(1))$ elements.

Let $X$ be the indicator function of $\{(x,1/x):x \in \mathbb F_p \setminus 0 \}$, and $Y$ the indicator function of $\{(x,y):x,y \in [1,m]\}$. The size of $A$ is the value of the inner product $\langle X,Y\rangle$.

To compute the inner product, we decompose $Y$ into a sum of Fourier coefficients.

Let $e(x)=\exp(2\pi i x/p)$, and let $K_\omega$ be the $\omega$-th coefficient of the  Fourier transform of the indicator function of the interval $[1,m]$, i.e. $K_\omega = \underset{x=1}{\overset{m}{\sum}}  e(\omega x)/p$, where $\omega=0,1,2,...,p-1$.

By the Fourier transform on cartesian products, $\langle X,Y\rangle = \underset{\psi=0}{\overset{p-1}{\sum}} \underset{\omega=0}{\overset{p-1}{\sum}} K_\psi K_\omega \langle e(\psi x)e(\omega y),X \rangle $.

Let $I_0$ be the term where $\psi$ and $\omega$ are both $0$, $I_1$ the sum of the terms where exactly one of $\psi$ and $\omega$ is $0$, and $I_2$ the sum of the terms where both $\psi$ and $\omega$ are nonzero. We have $\langle X,Y\rangle = I_0+I_1+I_2$ and $I_0=m^2(p-1)/p^2$.

To estimate $I_1$ and $I_2$, we need to bound the sum of $|K_\omega|$ over nonzero $\omega$. There is $K_\omega=\frac{e(\omega(m+1))-e(\omega)}{e(\omega)-1}/p$. As $|e(\omega)-1|=2\sin(\pi\omega/p)>4\omega/p$ when $0<\omega<p/2$, we have $|K_\omega|<\frac{2p}{4 \omega} /p = 1/2\omega$ when $0<\omega<p/2$. Thus the sum of $|K_\omega|$ over nonzero $\omega$ is $O(\log p)$.

The terms $K_\psi K_\omega \langle e(\psi x)e(\omega y),X \rangle$ appearing in $I_1$ has norm $K_\psi m/p$ when $\psi$ is nonzero or $K_\omega m/p$ when $\omega$ is nonzero, so $I_1=O(\log p)$.

If both $\psi$ and $\omega$ are nonzero, the term $\langle e(\psi x)e(\omega y),X \rangle$ can be estimated by the [Kloosterman sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kloosterman_sum) and it's $O(\sqrt{p})$. Summing over all nonzero $\psi$ and $\omega$, we have $I_2=O(\sqrt{p} \log^2 p)$.

Thus $\langle X,Y\rangle = I_0+I_1+I_2 = m^2(p-1)/p^2 + O(\log p)+O(\sqrt{p} \log^2 p) = (m/p)^2p(1-o(1))$.

This shows that the answer is false for any $c<1/4$.

Comment: You probably don't need this, but what about $(A+1)/A$? (I misread it like this initially but your statement seems to be true for it too)

Comment: (As well as for $A/A$, by the way)

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე This is not true for $A/A$, for example if $A$ is the set of squares.

Comment: @ThomasBloom Oh yes, thanks!

Comment: Some "worst cases", for small $|A|$: there seem to always be an $A$ with $|A|=3$ and $|A+1/A|\leqslant5$; $|A|=4$ and $|A+1/A|\leqslant8$; $|A|=5$ and $|A+1/A|\leqslant12$; $|A|=6$ and $|A+1/A|\leqslant15$, etc. Not sure if this can be used for a refutation, but still...

Comment: These minima are achieved at $A$ with $1/A=-A=A$; there might be other restrictions similar to that...

Comment: If size of the "worst" $|A+1/A|$ as function of $|A|$ is independent of $p$ and grows linearly, would this suffice for a negative answer? I think yes?

Comment: You need $c>1/4$ at least: take $A$ to be $I\cap I^{-1}$ where $I=[1,(1/2-\varepsilon)p]$.

Comment: ... and if $c>1/2$, then $A+A^{-1}=\mathbb F_p$ by the pigeonhole principle. Thus, we are left with $c\in[1/4,1/2]$ only.

Comment: @Seva Is it clear that there is a $c$ with $|I\cap I^{-1}|>cp$ for all $p$?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Yes, pretty clear: if $|I|>cp$, with a fixed $c>0$, then any standard argument gives $|I\cap I^{-1}|>(c^2-o(1))p$

Comment: @Seva "standard argument"? From probabilistic heuristic, this is what one would expect. But doesn't a rigorous proof need something about how the module $p$ inverses of the integers in $I$ are distributed in $[1, p]$? And why is $\lvert A+1/A\rvert=\lvert A+A\rvert$ small enough to produce a counterexample once $c<1/4$?

Comment: @PeterMueller: For the "standard argument"- a very basic finite Fourier analysis should work. Your second question is not quite clear to me - could you rephrase it?

Comment: @Seva The second question was nonsense.

Comment: @Seva I have updated the description of the question by using Kloosterman sums as the "standard argument".

Comment: @LeechLattice: Using Kloosterman sums looks like overkill to me, but it certainly works, anyway. However, I would rephrase the last sentence of your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The claim is true for $c > 1/4$, although the proof I have either requires the machinery of the arithmetic regularity lemma, or the (morally equivalent) language of additive limits (as discussed in [this blog post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2014/10/12/additive-limits/) of mine, or in [this paper of Szegedy](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3852460)). I will sketch a proof with the latter approach, which is shorter (it avoids a lot of "epsilon management"). One can expand this argument into a lengthier argument using instead the arithmetic regularity lemma (which would most likely give some tower-exponential type quantitative dependencies on constants), analogously to how arguments using graph limits (graphons) can often be converted into lengthier arguments relying instead on the Szemeredi regularity lemma, but I will leave this to the interested reader.

In what follows I assume familiarity with the language of nonstandard analysis and Loeb measure.

Suppose for contradiction that the claim failed, thus there is $c>1/4$ and $\varepsilon>0$ and a sequence $A_i \subset {\mathbb F}_{p_i}^*$ of sets of density $c + o(1)$ indexed by some primes $p_i$ going off to infinity such that $|A_i + 1/A_i| \leq (1-\varepsilon+o(1)) p_i$.  Taking an ultralimit, one obtains an internal subset $A$ of of a pseudofinite field ${\mathbb F} = {\mathbb F}_{p}$ (associated to a nonstandard prime $p$) of Loeb measure $c$ such that $A + \phi(A)$ has Loeb measure at most $1-\varepsilon$, where $\phi$ denotes the almost-everywhere defined inversion map $n \mapsto n^{-1}$.  In particular the convolution $1_A * 1_{\phi(A)}$ avoids a set of positive measure.

The $\sigma$-algebra ${\mathcal L}$ of Loeb-measurable subsets of ${\mathbb F}$ has two notable factors.  One is the Kronecker factor ${\mathcal K}$, generated by the eigenfunctions of $L^\infty({\mathcal L})$ with respect to the translation action (or equivalently, by the Fourier phases $n \mapsto \mathrm{st} e( an/p )$ for some non-standard $a \in {\mathbb F}$); the other is the pullback $\phi^* {\mathcal K}$ of the Kronecker factor ${\mathcal K}$ by the inversion map $\phi$.  Because of Kloosterman sum estimates, the two factors ${\mathcal K}, \phi^* {\mathcal K}$ are orthogonal.   The Kronecker factor is (up to some canonical isomorphisms) a compact abelian group (with Loeb measure restricting to the Haar probability measure on that group); in fact that compact abelian group is nothing more than the Pontryagin dual of the group of Fourier phases.  Because this latter group is torsion-free (it is isomorphic as a group to the pseudofinite field ${\mathbb F}$), the Kronecker factor is then a *connected* compact abelian group.

Because the Kronecker factor is characteristic for convolutions (see the previous references), we have the identity
$$ 1_A * 1_{\phi(A)} = {\bf E}(1_A|{\mathcal K}) * {\bf E}(1_{\phi(A)}|{\mathcal K})$$
Loeb-almost everywhere.  In particular,
$$ \mathrm{supp}({\bf E}(1_A|{\mathcal K})) + \mathrm{supp}({\bf E}(1_\phi(A)|{\mathcal K}))$$
fails to have full measure (here I gloss over a technical but fixable issue involving null sets).  Applying [Kemperman's theorem](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=202913)
$$ \mu( A + B ) \geq \min( \mu(A)+\mu(B), 1 )$$
valid for any connected compact group with Haar probability measure (actually for the technical reason mentioned earlier one should actually use [Pollard's theorem](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=354517) here, or the variant of Kemperman's theorem in [this blog post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/12/26/a-variant-of-kempermans-theorem/) of mine), we conclude that
$$ \mu(\mathrm{supp}({\bf E}(1_A|{\mathcal K}))) + \mu(\mathrm{supp}({\bf E}(1_\phi(A)|{\mathcal K}))) < 1,$$
thus ${\bf E}(1_A|{\mathcal K})$ is supported in a ${\mathcal K}$-measurable set $E$ of measure at most $\alpha$ and ${\bf E}(1_\phi(A)|{\mathcal K})$ is supported in a set of measure at most $1-\alpha$ for some $0 \leq \alpha \leq 1$.  Since $\phi$ is measure-preserving, we conclude that ${\bf E}(1_A|\phi^* {\mathcal K})$ is supported on a $\phi^* {\mathcal K}$-measurable set $F$ of measure at most $1-\alpha$.  In particular we have the pointwise bounds
$$ 1_A \leq 1_E$$
and
$$ 1_A \leq 1_F$$
Loeb-almost everywhere, hence
$$ 1_A \leq 1_E 1_F.$$
Loeb-almost everywhere.  Integrating and using the orthogonality of ${\mathcal K}$ and $\phi^* {\mathcal K}$, we conclude that
$$ c \leq \alpha(1-\alpha)$$
and hence
$$ c \leq 1/4,$$
giving the desired contradiction.

**Remark**: I think that a refinement of this argument in fact gives the lower bound $|A + 1/A| \geq (\min(2\sqrt{c}, 1)-o(1)) p$ for any fixed $0 \leq c \leq 1$, and a variant of Seva's construction should show that this bound is asymptotically best possible.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a partial answer based on (and slightly extending) my earlier comments.

- If $c>1/2$, then $A+A^{-1}=\mathbb F_p$ by the pigeonhole principle. We assume therefore that $c\le 1/2$.
- For any $c<1/4$ and sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$, there is a set $A$ with $|A|>cp$ and $|A+A^{-1}|<(1-\epsilon +o(1))p$. To see this let $m:=(1/2-\epsilon)p$ and $I:=[1,m]$ and notice that, by a simple averaging, there exists $x\in\mathbb F_p$ with $|(I+x)\cap I^{-1}|\ge m^2/p>(1/4-\epsilon)p$. Now let $A:=(I+x)\cap I^{-1}$. (This explains my comment about an overkill.)
- If I am not mistaken, then, subject to the finite field $(3n-4)$-conjecture, if $|A|>(1/3+\epsilon)p$, then $|A+A^{-1}|=(1-o(1))p$.

Comment: In the last bullet, do you mean $(1/3+\epsilon)p$ and $(1-o(1))p$?